# How to write a Pig UDF in Scala

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-pig

I am trying to write a Pig UDF in Scala (using Eclipse). I have added pig.jar as a library in the java build path which seems to resolve the 2 imports below:

- import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc
- import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple

however I get 2 errors which I cannot resolve:

1. org.apache.pig.EvalFunc[T] does not have a constructor
2. value get is not a member of org.apache.pig.data.Tuple (though I am sure that Tuple has the get method)

Here is the full code:

```
package datesUDFs
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
class getYear extends EvalFunc {
  val extractDate = """^(\d\d\d\d)-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d""".r
  def isDate(dtString: String): Boolean = extractDate.findFirstIn(dtString).nonEmpty

  override def exec(input: Tuple): Int = input.get(0) match {
    case dtString: String =>
      if (!isDate(dtString)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date string!")
      else (for (extractDate(year) <- extractDate.findFirstIn(dtString)) yield year).head.toInt
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid function call!")
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it! I added **hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar** and **commons-logging-1.1.3.jar** to my java build path and the problems were resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Besides having to specify the `EvalFunc` type parameter, your code compiles fine for me.

```
package datesUDFs
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
class getYear extends EvalFunc[Int] { // This is the only line I changed.
  val extractDate = """^(\d\d\d\d)-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d""".r
  def isDate(dtString: String): Boolean = extractDate.findFirstIn(dtString).nonEmpty

  override def exec(input: Tuple): Int = input.get(0) match {
    case dtString: String =>
      if (!isDate(dtString)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date string!")
      else (for (extractDate(year) <- extractDate.findFirstIn(dtString)) yield year).head.toInt
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid function call!")
  }
}
```

See if it help, sometimes ScalaIDE complains about the wrong things.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Unfortunately though I am still getting the same errors? Do you use Eclipse or are you compiling from shell? if so what's your command line? thanks again