# Is it possible to use PIG UDF in Spark / Scala ? How?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-pig, udf

Is it possible to use PIG UDF in Spark / Scala ? Both supports Java , so I thought we could. Can anybody share trick/ sample ?

Comment: Duplicate.See here [Pig udf in SCALA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778232/how-to-write-a-pig-udf-in-scala)

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Not really a duplicate: the question you've mentioned is about *writing* UDF in Scala, this one is about *using* existing UDF in Spark.

Comment: I think you need to write a wrapper around your Spark UDF so it uses the Pig UDF API.